# SOX - Slow audio without stuttering effect

Tags: audio

So, I have an audio file and I would like to slow it down to 0.5x it's speed without changing the pitch, the problem is that when I do that, I get a weird stuttering effect. Is there any way to have sox slow the audio "smoothly" so there's no noticeable stuttering? [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qL7I9BWFqdk) is an example that I have found where somebody slowed down the Windows XP startup sound to make it 24 hours long. If you skip to the middle of the video you will notice it is playing smoothly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it you're using the `tempo` effect? Have you tried playing around with the parameters, like reducing the segment size and increasing the search space and segment overlap, ending up with something like this:

```
play test.aiff tempo 0.5 10 20 30
```

Chances are, however, that you won't ever get a pleasing result using SoX to so drastically stretch audio without changing the pitch. Not that the SoX algorithm is bad, it just isn't quite the right tool for the job.
You'd be better off using something like [Amazing Slow Downer](https://www.ronimusic.com/slowdown.htm), or [Paul's Extreme Sound Stretch](http://hypermammut.sourceforge.net/paulstretch/), both employing algorithms specifically designed for stuff like this.

Comment: Are there any command line programs for this that support linux?

Comment: Sadly not that I'm aware of. Though there might be an appropriate LADSPA plugin available, but I have little experience with those.